# Getting a MalformedURLException in my tests but it never occurred before

Tags: java, url, exception

I upgraded my windows from 7 to 10 and now in my project I getting these exceptions when running the tests.

Here is my code

```
    @BeforeClass
public static void createSchema() throws Exception {

    log.info("Creating H2 CA_MANAGER schema");

    URL schemaDDL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("create_cam_test.sql");
    RunScript.execute(TestConfig.URL,
            TestConfig.USER, TestConfig.PASSWORD, schemaDDL.getFile(), null, false);

    log.info("Running H2 CA_MANAGER DDL");

    URL ddl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("ca_manager3_ddl_h2.sql");
    RunScript.execute(TestConfig.URL,
            TestConfig.USER, TestConfig.PASSWORD, ddl.getFile(), null, false);
}
```

Here is the exception.

```
 org.h2.message.DbException: IO Exception: "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql"; "/C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql" [90031-196]

    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:330)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:334)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.execute(RunScript.java:304)
    at 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql"; "/C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql" [90031-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newInputStream(FilePathDisk.java:317)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newInputStream(FileUtils.java:218)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:186)
    at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:329)
    ... 24 more
```

The exception occurs when I want to execute the script. 
Variable `schemaDDL.getFile()` returns the path exactly as seen in the exception:

```
/C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql
```

I also checked, it is definitely there. I also found solutions that stated `file://` needs to be appended to the path, I did so and still the same exception occurs. The file path looks as follow

```
file://C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql
```

The exception looks as follow

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: //C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql"; "file://C:/Users/Documents/camanager-combined/camanager.persistence.hibernate/target/test-classes/create_cam_test.sql" [90031-196]
```

Java version that I use is Java 1.8.0_121. Do you have any solutions.

Comment: Try changing schemaDDL.getFile() to schemaDDL.toString()

Comment: Are you using sprint boot.

Comment: @Rcordoval I get the same exception.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala No it does not make use of spring boot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
/C:/Users/francois17/Documents/.../create_cam_test.sql
```

is not a URL.  It is a pathname.

So the question is why is that triggering that problem?

Now it looks like it comes from this call:

```
RunScript.execute(TestConfig.URL,
        TestConfig.USER, TestConfig.PASSWORD, schemaDDL.getFile(), null, false);
```

or this one

```
RunScript.execute(TestConfig.URL,
        TestConfig.USER, TestConfig.PASSWORD, ddl.getFile(), null, false);
```

That looks OK, because the API for execute expects the 4th argument to be a pathname.

Then I looked at the site at which the URL is being created.   It is in [`org.h2.store.FileDiskPath::newInputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.h2database/h2/1.3.163/org/h2/store/fs/FilePathDisk.java#FilePathDisk.newInputStream%28%29).  The code for the method is:

```
public InputStream  newInputStream() throws IOException {
    if (name.indexOf(':') > 1) {
        // if the : is in position 1, a windows file access is assumed: C:.. or D:
        if (name.startsWith(CLASSPATH_PREFIX)) {
            String fileName = name.substring(CLASSPATH_PREFIX.length());
            if (!fileName.startsWith("/")) {
                fileName = "/" + fileName;
            }
            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            if (in == null) {
                 Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            }
            if (in == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("resource " + fileName);
            }
            return in;
        }
        // otherwise an URL is assumed
        URL url = new URL(name);
        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        return in;
    }
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(name);
    IOUtils.trace("openFileInputStream", name, in);
    return in;
}
```

To summarize what it does:

1. It looks for a colon in the pathname
2. If the colon is not the 2nd character:

   1. it looks for a "classpath:" URL and processes that.
   2. otherwise, it opens the URL as an ordinary URL
3. If there was no colon, or if the colon was the 2nd character (i.e. a Windows drive character), it opens the object as a file.

LIGHTBULB!

Look carefully at the pathname from above.  It *looks* like a pathname, but in fact it is malformed.  A Windows pathname with a drive SHOULD NOT start with a "/".   That extra "/" is causing the colon to be the 3rd character, which breaks the logic of the `newInputStream` method.

The correct format for a pathname with a drive is this:

```
C:/Users/francois17/Documents/.../create_cam_test.sql
```

Find where that bogus leading "/" has come from, and you've probably solved your problem.   You could also work around the bogus "/" by either removing it or prepending "file://".  (Note: 2 slashes ... because there is one there already!)

Comment: Hi there, so removing the prepending '/' works. Though as mentioned in the question adding file:// does not work. I did cater for the extra slash. I can't think to the life off me why is it adding that annoying '/' do you maybe have another approach of getting the path for my resource ?